# Generate events in new topic during Kafka Connect Sink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm developing a simple data flow, integrating information from an external rest service to a database using Kafka. A client can make a request and this generates a call to the service that sends N number of records into a topic. During the stream, some transformations are done and in the end all the records are ingested into a database using Kafka Connect Sink.

The problem I'm facing is how to notify the client when de data is available in the final database (MySQL). In my view, the easiest way would be to generate a new event in a control topic that the client can be subscribed to. This way, when all the records of the service are processed, the event is published and the client can query the database with the updated information.

To do this, I'm trying to use SMTs in then Sink connector.

A simplified schema will be like this:
[image]

My question is regading the Kafka Connect available SMTs: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/overview.html.

**Is there a way to route a record to a different topic in an SMT using the availables Kafka Connect Transformations?**

If the answer is no, it's possible to implement a custom SMT that replicates this behaviour or there is an easier aproach available?

Comment: Out of interest, what purpose is Kafka serving here? Why not write from the REST service to the database, and confirm the write success directly?

Comment: The purpose of Kafka in this use case is to integrate multiples sources of data in the same plataform on real time. We are currently capturing changes of our on-premise database using CDC. Then, we have a Kafka Streams process that cleans and aggregate those events before sinking them on our final database, which is going to be used by the web application. The REST API that I'm showing here contains data that is external to the company, but we want to make the same stream processing that we do to our own data when the client makes a request.  Is this a bad idea Robin? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: TBH this sounds more suited to a discussion e.g. at https://forum.confluent.io/c/architecture-and-design/29 than as a simple question here on SO. If you post your question & elaboration over there I'll try and help.

Comment: You could just use CDC from the downstream database as well

Comment: To directly answer the question, though, there's nothing preventing an SMT from writing to a topic, but MirrorMaker would make more sense if you're not actually transforming records

Comment: Thanks @RobinMoffatt, I'll elaborate the question in the forum too.

Comment: @OneCricketeer  The actual problem is how to generate a notification when the records are consumed by the Kafka Connect Sink, so the client can start querying the updated database. My plan was to read the SinkRercord inside a custom SMT to identify the last record of a request and then send an event to the control topic, so the application can notice it. I don't plan to transform records in the Sink context, but I want to ensure that the information is available before posting the notification. Note that all the topics are on the same cluster in Confluent Cloud.

Comment: You can track the consumer offset lag of the sink if your goal is to verify database records were actually written

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem